# How to get KDE Taskbar to display notifications icons on right

Tags: kubuntu, panel, taskbar

I was trying to fix some settings on the taskbar panel and all the tray icons, such as the clock, the clipboard, the search service etc have all now moved to the left side of the taskbar. Is there some way to get them back to the left?

I have tried changing the alignment via the  Panel Settings>More Settings>Panel Alignment menu, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KDE UserBase**

http://userbase.kde.org/Welcome_to_KDE_UserBase

> How-To's, Tips & Tricks that can help make your KDE software
>   experience more enjoyable and productive.

**KDE UserBase Plasma**

http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma

**KDE UserBase Plasma/Panel**

http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Panels

> Configuration
>
> The panel can then be configured by clicking on the toolbox located on
>   the right for horizontal or bottom for vertical panel. At that point,
>   the panel will be in configuration mode. Panel configuration may also
>   be accessed via the context (right click) menu in the panel.
>
> Widgets in the panel can be sorted by dragging them when in
>   configuration mode. Widgets align left in the horizontal and top in
>   the vertical panel

You could add a new default panel - right click the desktop:

[image]

When you are in the configuration mode there is the "compas rose" on the top of the movable object:

[image]

Comment: Add comment. I have the 'compass rose' thing and they all refuse to stay on the right. They snap back as soon as I release the mouse.